# I had tried to make chrome extension but i have troubles

Tags: html, css, json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

So i had tried make litle chrome extension just to change color in csgosquad.com/ranks [color of thoose orange bars to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJIfU.png)

using manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Top Questions redder",
  "description": "Make the world red",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["https://csgosquad.com/ranks"],
    "css": ["sheet.css"],
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and sheet.css

```
`.row-rank .progress.bar-rank .progress-bar
{
    background-color: #ff0b00;
}`
```

but i still need to change it manualy [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4rtN.gif)

**So what to do to get it change automatically?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **three** points,

1. Remove the last "," within content_scripts
2. Remove "`" within sheet.css
3. Add "!important" to make sure your css have a higher specificity

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Top Questions redder",
    "description": "Make the world red",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://csgosquad.com/ranks"
            ],
            "css": [
                "sheet.css"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

sheet.css

```
.row-rank .progress.bar-rank .progress-bar
{
    background-color: #ff0b00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... it seems that the code are almost Ok, but I found one problem.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://csgosquad.com/ranks"],
    "css": ["sheet.css"],
  }
],
```

The comma put on the end of the line *"css": ["sheet.css"],*. Probably, this manifest.json file is invalid. You should confirm whether your extension was registered successfully on chrome://extensions page.